# Determine the amount of solutions for every real number "a" to the following system of linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm studying linear algebra and I have received the following problem to solve:

"Determine the amount of solutions for every real number "a" to the following system of linear equations."

$      (4-a)x_1+2x_2-x_3=1 \\
    -2x_1+(1-a)x_2+2x_3=2\\
     -x_1+2x_2+(4-a)x_3=1 $

I have a hard time interpreting the problem I think. According to my literature, for a system of linear equations, there will be either

- One unique solution,
- An infinite amount of solutions or
- No solution

for every real number "a".

How do you check for each real number "a" which one of these three cases that is true, without actually testing for each real number?

Any input is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Just do gaussian symplification and before you obtain your first variable (some of the x's) you must have a fraction with a's. Then find for which values the denominator will be 0 (no solution) and for which both the numerator and denominator will be 0 (infinite solutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of the coefficient matrix *in terms of $a$* factors nicely as $-(a-1)(a-3)(a-5)$, so for $a\ne1,3,5$ the system has exactly one solution.

For $a=1$ and $a=3$ the rank of the coefficient matrix drops to $2$ but the augmented matrix (with the right-hand sides added) still has rank $3$, so there are no solutions in these cases. For $a=5$ we get $2$ and $2$ respectively, so there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: This very much seems to solve the problem. Another problem is that I'm not really great with matrix calculation, which otherwise would save me a lot of time. The first two lines in your answer is what I essentially need to figure out and why it is valid. I understand it would be a lot to expand on that. Do you think it's possible to get to the same argument but in non-matrix form or is it necessary using matrix notation involving the determinant?

Comment: @ZimmerJ Gaussian elimination alone should work, but is more tedious (you would have to reason about divisions by zero in the middle of the elimination depending on $a$).

Comment: @ZimmerJ If we test for $a = 1$ we get these vectors from the coefficients of $x_1, x_2, x_3$: $(3, 2, -1), (-2, 0, 2), (-1, 2, 3)$. Now $-((-2, 0, 2) + (-1, 2, 3)) = (3, -2, -5)$. So the reason there is no unique solution cannot be that there are infinitely many solutions, because we can't write the third vector as a linear combination of the other two. This means that the system of equations we have is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

It is more convenient to use matrix notation to express this system.

$$\begin{pmatrix}4 -a & 2 & -1  &|&1\\ -2 & 1-a & 2 &|& 2 \\ -1 & 2 & 4 -a &|& 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Applying elementary row operations, we can make $R_1 = R_1 - R_3$, $R_3 = R_3 - R1$ which results in

$$\begin{pmatrix} 5 -a & 0 & -5+a  &|&0\\ -2 & 1-a & 2 &|& 2 \\ -5+a & 0 & 5 -a &|& 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

We can divide $R_1, R_3$ both by $5-a$ (assuming $a \neq 5$) to obtain

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1  &|&0\\ -2 & 1-a & 2 &|& 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 &|& 0 \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1  &|&0\\ -2 & 1-a & 2 &|& 2 \end{pmatrix} \to  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1  &|&0\\ 0 & 1-a & 0 &|& 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

The system to which we have arrived has solutions for any $a$. Namely, it will be solved by any coefficients $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ such that $x_1 = x_3, x_2=0$.

These already tells you the number of solutions the system has for $a$ any real number except $5$. Can you see what happens if $a = 5$?

Comment: I also got to these results: a=5 → x₁=-1,  2x₂=x₃  → Infinite amount of solutions. But a≠5 is what's hard for me to understand, because according to the original problem I have to determine the amount of solutions for every a≠5? I also tested with a=1 which couldn't be a solution?